# How to assign an IP to Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have installed a K8S cluster via Rancher and it is up and running. For testing purpose, I've deployed a helloworld nginx pod:

[image]

To call the service, I have to call the NodePort IP address, for example:

```
http://111.111.111.111:30359/
```

But I would like to call it by a name, for example:

```
https://helloworld.co.example.org
```

The ingress controller Nginx is installed:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default         kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  162m
dev             helloworld             ClusterIP   10.43.187.230   <none>        80/TCP                   17m
dev             helloworld-nodeport    NodePort    10.43.9.147     <none>        80:30359/TCP             17m
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend   ClusterIP   10.43.86.105    <none>        80/TCP                   161m
kube-system     kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.43.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   161m
kube-system     metrics-server         ClusterIP   10.43.220.198   <none>        443/TCP                  161m
```

But it does not have `EXTERNAL-IP`. The question is, how to get it.

Comment: where the cluster deployed? local system or on Prem or public cloud?

Comment: On DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) type service will never create an EXTERNAL IP because it's cluster-internal IP. Follow this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm) on how to use nginx ingress on digital ocean to expose hello world app via a hostname.

Following the guide after you install the nginx ingress controller it will be exposed by a LoadBalancer provided by digital ocean.

As you can see in the guide you will use your domain in the ingress rules.You’ll need to ensure that your domain is pointed to the Load Balancer via A records. This is done through your DNS provider.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: helloworld.co.example.org
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes
          servicePort: 80
```